# Wood showing in my foundation should I be concerned?

Tags: foundation

[image]I live in North Texas , recently I noticed wood showing at the bottom of my house. I'm wondering if I should be concerned and what, if anything, I can do about this?[image][[image: enter image description here][1]]

Comment: Just seeing the edge, it is hard to tell.  Wood on the outside of the cement not bad, wood inside the cement not good.

Comment: Looks likely to just be a scrap of the forms used when they poured the concrete, but as @crip659 said, it's hard to be sure from the photo .

Comment: Do you have a basement or crawlspace? If so, can you see wood on the inside here?

Comment: No basement or crawl space. This is North Texas so we don't have those.